# Convert deeply nested class object to plain object while preserving methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

There's a class object (deeply nested with more class objects) and I'd like to convert it to  plain `Object` type while preserving methods (getters, setters, etc).

```js
class A {
    id = "";
    data = {
        sync: {}
    };

}

class SyncService {
    syncResultServiceA = {
        ToSync: 0,
        Synced: 0,
        SyncErrors: [],
    };
    syncResultServiceB = {
        ToSync: 0,
        Synced: 0,
        Errors: [],
    };
}
```

```js
const a = new A();
a.data.sync = new SyncService();
console.log(a.data.sync.constructor.name) // "SyncService"
```

I tried bunch of solutions: `{...obj}` wouldn't work for nested class objects, `JSON.stringify() + parse()` would remove custom methods, etc.

Comment: You would need to iterate recursively over the fields/values, checking if they are classes, and convert them using Object.assign/spread operator.

Comment: "Plain object" and "preserve methods" seem like opposing goals to me. What are you actually trying to do, what do you need this for?

Comment: I know it's a weird but real requirement. I'm storing data in Firebase firestore db, but it wouldn't take the class object (created with new operator). on top of it, I need to pass date prop as Firestore.Timestamp type which has some getters and setters

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.id = '';
    this.data = {
      sync: {},
    };
  }

}

class SyncService {
  constructor() {
    this.syncResultServiceA = {
      ToSync: 0,
      Synced: 0,
      SyncErrors: [],
    };
    this.syncResultServiceB = {
      ToSync: 0,
      Synced: 0,
      Errors: [],
    };
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.data.sync = new SyncService();
console.log(a.data.sync.constructor.name) // "SyncService"

const b = convertToPlainObject(a);
console.log(b.data.sync.constructor.name);

function convertToPlainObject(cls) {
  const copy = {
    ...cls
  };
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(copy)) {
    if (typeof v === 'object') {
      copy[k] = convertToPlainObject(v);
    }
  }
  return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion to go through all the nested objects and convert them. Here is an example:

```js
class A {
    id = "";
    data = {
        sync: {}
    };

}

class SyncService {
    syncResultServiceA = {
        ToSync: 0,
        Synced: 0,
        SyncErrors: [],
    };
    syncResultServiceB = {
        ToSync: 0,
        Synced: 0,
        Errors: [],
    };
}
const a = new A();
a.data.sync = new SyncService();
console.log(a.data.sync.constructor.name) // "SyncService"

const toPlain = (o) => {
  if (typeof o === 'object' && !Array.isArray(o)) {
    return {...Object.keys(o).reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = toPlain(o[c]), a), {})};
  }
  return o;
}

const plain = toPlain(a);
console.log(plain.data.sync.constructor.name) // "Object"
```

Comment: it fails when property value is `null`. because typeof null is actually object.